# Python: "IndexError: string index out of range", but there is no string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing

This is part of a kata on [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com), where the goal is to build a function that can take a 9x9 2D array (nested list) of numbers, representing a sudoku puzzle, and solve it.

My solution passes one of the tests but fails the second, and I'm unable to see exactly what input is causing this failure.
It mentions that the string index error happens in this piece of code:

```
def square_check(row_num, col_num):
    r, c = row_num % 3, col_num % 3
    rbase, cbase = row_num - r, col_num - c
    return [puzzle[rbase+(r+1)%3][cbase+(c+1)%3], 
            puzzle[rbase+(r+1)%3][cbase+(c+2)%3], 
            puzzle[rbase+(r+2)%3][cbase+(c+1)%3], 
            puzzle[rbase+(r+2)%3][cbase+(c+2)%3]]
```

which returns a list of the numbers that are in the appropriate 3x3 square for each unknown square of the puzzle (the 9x9 array) given by the indexes row_num and col_num. It only looks at four squares because the other four are checked elsewhere.

As far as I can tell there are no strings here to index, let alone to produce index errors. The only thing I am indexing is the 9x9 array, but those numbers are always between 0 and 8 and if they weren't I would expect a list index error. I'm sure it's not a problem with the modular arithmetic because it works in my compiler on every puzzle I've given it, even ones where for example all corners of the 9x9 array are unknown.

Comment: Do you get console output? You can try `print(type(r))` etc. I'd guess they're trying to pass string inputs to your function. The exact error message would help.

Comment: The assignment to *puzzle* would also help. Is it really a global variable?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that the first test used a global variable called puzzle, (and so did I in my tests), but in the subsequent tests they didn't. I changed square_check to take the puzzle as an input and passed all the tests. Should I delete this question?